# Diagonal elements four dimensional array

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

Let's say you have a four dimensional array with two digit numbers:

```
12 22 34 45

33 01 02 05

04 98 21 13

03 21 45 11
```

I'm trying to list the diagonals in this script, but it's not working. The diagonals in this case are:

```
12, 1, 21, 11, 45, 2, 98, 3.
```

I don't have a debugger so I can't figure out what's wrong, but I have a feeling it's because of the if statement I wrote, primarily the `row == column - 3`, which technically defines the placement of 45, 02, 98 and 3 I believe. What is being done wrong here? (The array insertion is cut out from this.)

```
#include <iostream> //Older version of C++, not modern.
using namespace std;

for (int row = 0; row < 4; row++){
    for (int column = 0; column <= 4; column++){
        if (row == column || row==column-3){
            cout << array[row][column] << " ";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is 2 dimensional array with dimension `[4][4]`. BTW `row==column-3` should be `row == 3 - column`

Comment: `I don't have a debugger`
but why?

Comment: @mohit Thanks! I see where it applies.

Comment: why column <= 4 but not column < 4??

Comment: "//Older version of C++, not modern" That's a weird comment. What do you think a modern version would have in place of this line?

Comment: er....... I have no idea @shole, it was just the way I saw it done, but the output is still the same if <= and < for the statement

Comment: @n.m the moment i posted this question i thought the same thing, only added it because 1 of my other questions had a lot of #include <string> stuff answers, rly shouldn't have for this 1

Comment: it is wrong when row = 1 and column = 4, what is array[1][4]?  Also I think it should be row == 3-column to give  {(0,3), (1,2),(2,1),(3,0)}

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream> //Older version of C++, not modern.
using namespace std;

for (int row = 0; row < 4; row++)
{
for (int column = 0; column <= 4; column++)
{
if (row == column || row == 3 - column)  // Not column - 3
{
    cout << array[row][column] << " ";
}
}
}
```